# How can I make Pidgin a single-window application?

Tags: window, pidgin

I can reduce Pidgin to two windows, but no further. The Buddy List is always separate from whatever grouped chat window I create. Is there any way to combine it?

---

I have come across these plugins, but they don't have Ubuntu-specific instructions:

- https://github.com/dm0-/window_merge
- https://github.com/sardemff7/pidgin-single-window

Comment: There is now a Debian packaging request https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=721265

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I successfully installed window_merge in ubuntu following these  guidelines:

http://tuxdna.in/blog/2014/08/12/single-window-mode-in-pidgin-messenger-using-window-merge-plugin/

I had to install those packages:

- pidgin-dev
- libgtk-3-dev

I also had to install it in a different way:

```
sudo make install
```

Now it works like a charm. Hope this helps.

Comment: After sudo make install and restarting pidgin, I do not see window merge in the plugin list. (14.04)

Comment: I had to copy the files from /usr/local/lib/pidgin to /home/user/.purple/plugins and then it worked.

Comment: Current project download page is ... github.com/dm0-/window_merge/downloads  ... Installing libraries and copying files was obligatory for me. Otherwise ./config failed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with Pidgin, and from the looks of things, doesn't seem like a feature we will get any time soon.

Maybe someone will eventually package those plugins you mentioned, but as far as I read at least [one plugin](http://www.bloggish.net/2010/06/pidgin-with-less-windows.html) requires external patches, which is not a good long term solution until they are upstreamed.